# Spring classloader loads class multiple times when context:load-time-weaver is used

Tags: spring, aspectj

I would like to ask why does the spring classloader load java classes multiple times when `<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" />` is used in xml config?

I can see spring is using

`org.springframework.context.support.ContextTypeMatchClassLoader$ContextOverridingClassLoader`

classloader, which, as I read in documentation, creates new classloader instance for each loaded class. In our current project this results in 11 loaded classes of the same type - 1 using parent classloader and 10 more using `ContextOverridingClassLoader` (each loaded in its own). What could be the cause of this? If we startup many applications in parallel, these duplicate classes eat up too mach permgen memory (resulting in crash). We could just increase permgen memory of course, but I was curious if there  is anything else to do.

As soon as I remove this configuration parameter, spring loads  all classes only once. I checked this using -XX:+TraceClassLoading VM option and heapdumps.

We are using Spring 3.2.4 and AspectJ 1.7.4

**Update:**

After I upgraded to Spring 4.2.1, each class is now loaded 15 times. Could it be somehow connected to spring aspects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up calling GC after application context initialization, thus reducing the amount of used memory during parallel startup of many applications (a good tradeoff to longer application startup) as each application cleans up after init.